# How to calculate a grade for a class using lists and functions in Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, python-3.x, computer-science

I need to write a program that calculates a grade for a class based on the following input and processes:

1. Ask the user for the number of tests, assignments, quizzes, and labs in their course.
2. Ask the user if there is a final with a separate weight from the tests above, e.g. a course has 2 tests, each weighing 12.5%, and 1 final weighing 15%.
3. For each category having a number > 0 a. Prompt the user for the weighted percent, out of 100%, which should total 100% for all categories!!! b. Get the score(s) for the category. c. If the category is labs, then sum all the scores. d. Else, average the scores. e. Calculate the weighted average for the category.
4. Using the weighted average of each category, calculate the grade in the course.
5. Ask the user if he/she wants to calculate a grade for another class.
6. If the user responds yes, then go back to step 1. 7. Else, end the program.

I am almost finished with the program and have all of my functions but I am having difficulty making it all come together and work properly. My first problem is incorporating steps 5/6 and getting the while loop to work with the rest of the code. Additionally, I am having difficulty summing the lab scores and incorporating that value into the weighted average.

Any help is much appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
def main():
       inputList = get_user_input()
       average = get_scores(inputList)
       weightedAvgs = get_weightedavg(average, inputList)
       results = get_class_grade(weightedAvgs)

       ans = "yes"
       while(ans == "yes"):
            def get_user_input():
                    inputList = [] # initializes a list
            # Gets how many scores for each category the user would like to enter and adds value to a list
                    tests = int(input("How many tests scores would you like to enter? "))
                    inputList.append(tests)
                    assignments = int(input("How many assignment scores would you like to enter: "))
                    inputList.append(assignments)
                    quizzes = int(input("How many quiz scores would you like to enter? "))
                    inputList.append(quizzes)
                    labs = int(input("How many lab scores would you like to enter? "))
                    inputList.append(labs)
                    final = int(input("How many final scores would you like to enter? "))
                    inputList.append(final)

            # Gets the weight of each category if there are any scores to enter and adds the value to a list
                    if tests > 0:
                            testWeight = float(input("Enter the weight of tests: "))
                            inputList.append(testWeight)
                    else:
                            testWeight = 0
                    if assignments > 0:
                            assignmentWeight = float(input("Enter the weight of assignments: "))
                            inputList.append(assignmentWeight)
                    else:
                            assignmentWeight = 0
                    if quizzes > 0:
                            quizWeight = float(input("Enter the weight of quizzes: "))
                            inputList.append(assignmentWeight)
                    else:
                            quizWeight = 0
                    if labs > 0:
                            labWeight = float(input("Enter the weight of labs: "))
                            inputList.append(labWeight)
                    else:
                            labWeight = 0
                    if final > 0:
                            finalWeight = float(input("Enter the weight of the final: "))
                            inputList.append(finalWeight)
                    else:
                            finalWeight = 0

                    return(inputList)

            def get_scores(inputList):
            # Gets scores for each category & calculates avg for each category
                    average = []
                    testScoreList = []
                    tests2 = inputList[0]
                    for x in range(tests2):
                            testScore = float(input("Enter your test score: "))
                            testScoreList.append(testScore)
                    if tests2 == 0:
                            testAvg = 0
                    else:
                            testAvg = sum(testScoreList) / inputList[0]
                    average.append(testAvg)


                    assignmentScoreList = []
                    assignments2 = inputList[1]
                    for x in range(assignments2):
                            assignmentScore = float(input("Enter your assignment score: "))
                            assignmentScoreList.append(assignmentScore)
                    if assignments2 == 0:
                            assignmentAvg = 0
                    else:
                            assignmentAvg = sum(assignmentScoreList) / inputList[1]
                    average.append(assignmentAvg)


                    quizScoreList = []
                    quizzes2 = inputList[2]
                    for x in range(quizzes2):
                            quizScore = float(input("Enter your quiz score: "))
                            quizScoreList.append(quizScore)
                    if quizzes2 == 0:
                            quizAvg = 0
                    else:
                            quizAvg = sum(quizScoreList) / inputList [2]
                    average.append(quizAvg)


                    labScoreList = []
                    labs2 = inputList[3]
                    for x in range(labs2):
                            labScore = float(input("Enter your lab score: "))
                            labScoreList.append(labScore)
                    if labs2 == 0:
                            labSum = 0
                    else:
                            labSum = sum(labScoreList)
                    average.append(labSum)


                    finalScoreList = []
                    final2 = inputList[4]
                    for x in range(final2):
                            finalScore = float(input("Enter the score for your final: "))
                            finalScoreList.append(finalScore)
                    if final2 == 0:
                            finalAvg = 0
                    else:
                            finalAvg = sum(finalScoreList) / inputList[4]
                    average.append(finalAvg)


            def get_weighted_avg(average, inputList):
                    weightedAvgs = []

                    weightedTestAvg = average[0] * inputList[5]
                    weightedAvgs.append(weightedTestAvg)
                    print("Your weighted average is " + str(weightedTestAvg))

                    weightedAssignmentAvg = average[1] * inputList[6]
                    weightedAvgs.append(weightedAssignmentAvg)
                    print("Your weighted average is " + str(weightedAssignmentAvg))

                    weightedQuizAvg = average[2] * inputList[7]
                    weightedAvgs.append(weightedQuizAvg)
                    print("Your weighted average is " + str(weightedAssignmentAvg))

                    weightedLabSum = average[3] * inputList[8]
                    weightedAvgs.append(weightedLabSum)
                    print("The sum of your lab scores are " + str(weightedLabAvg))

                    weightedFinalAvg = average[4] * inputList[9]
                    weightedAvgs.append(weightedFinalAvg)
                    print("Your weighted average is " + str(weightedFinalAvg))

                    return(weightedAvgs)

            def get_class_grade(weightedAvgs):
                    grade = weightedAvgs[0] + weightedAvgs[1] + weightedAvgs[2] + weightedAvgs[3] + weightedAvgs[4]

                    if grade >= 90:
            finalGrade = "A"
                    elif grade >= 80:
                            finalGrade = "B"
                    elif grade >= 70:
                            finalGrade = "C"
                    elif grade >= 60:
                            finalGrade = "D"
                    else:
                            finalGrade = "F"

                    print("Your grade is " + finalGrade)
                    ans = (input("Would you like to calculate a grade for another class? "))
                    while(ans != "yes" and ans != "no"):
                            print("Please type yes or no")
                            ans = (input("Would you like to calculate a grade for another class? "))
    if ans == "no":
            exit()
main()
```

Comment: Why are you embedding your functions inside the while loop ?

Comment: Your code complexity is really making it hard to read. Please consider, reorganizing your code in such way that the main loop only includes a small number of lines, which can be calls to other functions.

Comment: @Oz123 I am not sure how to incorporate the while loop. My thought process was that if I wrapped the while loop around all of my code (including functions), everything inside of it would run as long as the condition is true. To address your second comment, I'm sorry but I don't know how to do that. I am new to programming.

Comment: For starters, you need to move your function definitions outside of that `while` loop. First you define functions, and then you call them. Please take a look at an [introductory Python tutorial](http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F); it's not really practical (or appropriate) for SO to try to teach that material. And once you've done that it will also be helpful to take a look at code written by others to see the usual way to organize things in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to go through and re-organise your code for you because it is something you really need to work through. Instead, I will provide examples on how to use `while-loops`.

**while True and break**

Using `while True` you can continuously run the code that follows. Using a condition you can then use `break` to exit the loop at that point

```
while True:
    # Will request a number and print it back to the user
    # If a valid entry is entered print and exit while loop
    # Otherwise while loop will continue
    user_input = input('Please enter a number: ')
    if user_input.isdigit(): # Checks if the input string is a number
        print('You entered {0}'.format(user_input))
        break # exit loop
    else:
        print('That is not a number')
```

**while with incrementing**

Another method is using a variable and incrementing it after each iteration. Once the counter reaches a certain number and falsifies the condition then the loop exits once the iteration is finished.

```
counter = 0
input_list = []
print('Please enter a valid non-number 5 times')
while counter < 5: # Exits when condition is false | counter >= 5
    user_input = input('Please enter a non-number: ')
    if not user_input.isdigit(): # Checks if the input string is a number
        input_list.append(user_input) # Add input to list
        counter += 1 # Increments counter by 1
    else:
        print("That's a number")

print(input_list)
```

**while with bool value and using functions**

You can use your functions defined outside the while loop continuously until the condition is false. In this example the double function is used each time until the user enters 'q' or 'Q'. The variable is the made `True` which makes the condition `False` and ends the loop.

```
def double(value):
    return value * 2

print('Find the result of double a value. Enter q to Quit')
exit_loop = False
while not exit_loop: # Same effect as while not False == while True
    user_input = input('Please enter a value: ')
    if user_input.lower() == 'q':
        exit_loop = True # exit loop
    elif user_input.isdigit(): # Checks if the input string is a number
        num = int(user_input)
        print(double(num))
    else:
        print(double(user_input))
```

**Side notes** when checking the using input of a string there are a few ways to do it. These examples are all valid and not limited to -

```
if user_input.lower() == 'q':
if user_input == 'q' or user_input == 'Q':
if user_input in 'qQ':
```